# Speed and motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, projectile

If you your traveling in a forward motion at a certain speed and throw an object in the opposite direction at the same speed shouldn't it fall straight down to the ground.

Comment: Depends upon who is looking. If you (moving person) look at it, it would appear like a normal throw. For someone standing on the ground, it would look like falling streight down.

Comment: [Yes.](https://youtube.com/watch?v=BLuI118nhzc)

Comment: Mythbusters demonstrated this effect exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed.  I can't resist answering with [This clip from Mythbusters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLuI118nhzc) which demonstrates exactly what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the frame of reference. With respect to the man who throws the object, it will travel at a speed equal to the speed at which it was thrown. With respect to the ground, it'll fall straight down.